# Use multiple column variables in bash script to pull output from routers

Tags: bash, variables

I have a script that logs on to routers and pulls output that is named routerauto.  I would like to use data from a text file to automatically populate required commands to pull required info from a large number of routers.

Ultimately I would like the script to move through each line of the text file, filling in the gaps with the output from the columns as below.  The text file uses tab as separator.

```
routerauto VARIABLE1 "sh service id VARIABLE2 sap VARIABLE4 detail"
```

Example data:

```
hostnamei       serv-id cct             sap
london-officei  123456  No987654321     8/1/4:100
```

Example output:

```
routerauto london-office "sh service id 123456 sap 8/1/4:100 detail"
```

Comment: Better provide an actual sample and intended output.

Comment: Fixed "example data" according to the text of the question. Please review if this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `bash` only solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read hostnamei servid cct sap; do
    echo routerauto $hostnamei \"sh service id $servid sap $sap detail\"
done < <(tail -n +2 sample.data)
```

Producing given your sample file:

```
routerauto london-officei "sh service id 123456 sap 8/1/4:100 detail"
```

Please note this assume no space are allowed in your various data fields.